# Fortran: efficient matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: optimization, fortran, matrix-multiplication, blas

I have a piece of code which is a significant bottleneck:

```
    do s = 1,ns
        msum = 0.d0
        do k = 1,ns
            msum = msum + tm(k,s)*f(:,:,k)
        end do
        m(:,:,s) = msum
    end do
```

This is a simple matrix-vector product `m=tm*f` (where `f` is length `k`) for every `x,y`.

I thought about using a BLAS routine but i am not sure if any allows multiplying along a specific dimension (`k`). Do any of you have any good advice?

Comment: Can you redesign `f` so that `k` is the first dimension?

Comment: yes i can, it is relatively easy but then the data is non-contiguous in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you do not mention the actual shape of `f`, i.e. the number of `x` and `y`. Since you mention this piece of code to be a bottleneck, you can and should replace `msum` and use the memory `m(:,:,s)` and spare the first step in you loop, e.g.

```
do s = 1,ns
    m = tm(k,1)*f(:,:,k)
    do k = 2, ns
        m(:,:,s) = m(:,:,s) + tm(k,s)*f(:,:,k)
    end do
end do
```

**Secondly, a more general appraoch**
There are `ns` summations of `nK` 2D matrices `f(:,:,1:nK)` by means of scalar factors that are stored in `tm(:,1:ns)`. The goal is to store these sums in `m(:,:,1:ns)`. Why not sum up element-wise wrt `x` and `y` to exploit contiguuos memory sections by means of the result? You already mentioned that you can redesign such that `k` is the first dimension in `f`, i.e. `f(k,:,:)`.

Considering only the desired outcome, you ought to have `ns` 2D matrices `m(:,:,1:ns)` that are independent of each other (outer loop remains at it is). Lets drop this dimension for a moment. The problem then becomes:

> m(:,:) = \sum_{k=1}^{ns}   tm_k * f_k(:,:)

We should thus sum over `k`, e.g. have `f(k,:,:)` to determine `m(:,:)` as follows (note that I am adding the outer loop for `s` again):

```
nK = size(f, 1)  ! the "k"s
nX = size(f, 2)  ! the "x"s
nY = size(f, 3)  ! the "y"s
m = 0.d0
do s = 1, ns
    do ii = 1, nY
        call DGEMV('N', nK, nY, &
                   1.d0, f(:,:,nY), 1, tm(:,s), 1, &
                   1.d0, m(:,nY,s), 1)
    end do !ii
end do !s
```

See the documentation of [DGEMV](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/dgemv.html) for more details on its usage.

Of course, the above advice of excluding the first step of the loop to spare the initialization by means of zeros may be applied at well.

Comment: very interesting! i will implement and see if there is any improvement. Since you ask, the size of x,y depend on domain size but lets say for now they are fixed at 100. the size of k is fixed at 9.

Comment: @nlooije Regarding the size of x and y: depending on the actual speed-up through BLAS (or rather use OpenBLAS, it's faster!), reordering the dimensions may or may not increase the overall speed of your algorithm. However, this is specific to your problem and code and should be worth testing.